# Existence of special system of values.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There is a graph $G=(V,E)$, where $|V|=n$.
Let's consider every induced subgraph of $G$ with $k$ vertices. I denote cardinality of $l$-th induced subgraph (its edges) as $a_{l}$ and i call it a $l$-th value of a graph.

> There is given a system of values $(a_{1},...,a_{{n\choose k}})$. Find the a way to decide whether this system is set of values of some graph.

I even don't know how to approach this problem.

Regards.

Comment: Do we know the set of vertices of each $l$-th induced subgraph or we only know for each number $x$ from $0$ to ${k\choose 2}$ how many $a_l$’s are equal to $x$?